# Xamarin Forms how to remove debug version from android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

A while ago I created a small application in Xamarin Forms and ran it with Visual Studio on my Android device. After a while I uninstalled it on my phone, however every time I restart my phone the app wants to install again. This is impossible while it no longer exists. I searched a lot but I cannot find a file on my phone. Also looked into the logging of the phone, but also could not find a lead. Also I have not found an answer on stack or on Google. Has anyone encountered this problem and has a solution?
I have a Xiaomi Mi 5 with Miui 10 which is Android 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the answer from o_w I found the working solution. I could not uninstall, while the package was not found on my phone when using `adb shell pm list packages`. So I ended up running the application with Visual Studio in release mode again on my phone, I had to try a couple of times before it showed up on the list. When it finally showed up, I uninstalled with `adb uninstall <packagename>` I got the correct package name from the list.

Answer (score 1):

Try while device is connected:
Go to Visual studio menu -> Tools -> Android -> Android ADB Command prompt and enter in the console window:
adb uninstall com.[your apk name]
and check phone again.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try later on today and if it works I will upvote

Comment: So I tried this, and it partly helped me. I could not uninstall, while the package was not found on my phone when using adb shell pm list packages.
So I ended up running the application with Visual Studio in release mode again on my phone, I had to do try a couple of times before it showed up on the list. When it finally showed up, I uninstalled with the above solution. I got the correct package name from the list.